# Dividing a sphere into multiple texture

Tags: three.js

I have a sphere with texture of earth that I generate on the fly with the canvas element from an SVG file and manipulate it.

The texture size is 16384x8192 , and less than this - it's look blurry on close zoom.

But this is a huge texture size and causing memory problems... (But it's look very good when it is working)

I think a better approach would be to split the sphere into 32 separated textures, each in size of 2048x2048

A few questions:

1. How can I split the sphere and assign the right textures?
2. Is this approach better in terms of memory and performance from a single huge texture?
3. Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what your issues are. **2** `16,384 x 8,192 == 2 x 8,192 x 8,192 == 2 x 2 x 2 x 4,096 x 4,096 == 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2,048 x 2,048 === 32 x 2,048 x 2048` memory wise it's the same amount of memory... but without a crystal ball, it's impossible to tell which memory you are referring to.

Comment: **1** so broad i don't even know where to begin. I've actually tried... `myMeshChunk.material.texture = myTextureChunk` - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: **3** and **1**, the answer was provided but you didn't consider it and left a vague comment to why it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can use paintbrush, a free software, to change the resolution of your picture. In paintbrush go to tools, image size, select your size

Answer (score 0):

You could subdivide a cube, and cubemap this.

Instead of having one texture per face, you would have NxN textures. 32 doesn't sound like a good number, but 24 for example does, (6x2x2).

You will still use the same amount of memory. If the shape actually needs to be spherical you can further subdivide the segments and normalize the entire shape (spherify it).

You probably cant even use such a big texture anyway.

**notice the top sphere (cubemap, ignore isocube):**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, But a cube is not a good solution, because the map of the earth will not be placed correctly on a cube

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Please explain `" because the map of the earth will not be placed correctly on a cube"`

Answer (score -1):

1. Typically, that's not something you'd do programmatically, but in a 3D program like Blender or 3D max. It involves some trivial mesh separation, UV mapping and material assignment. One other approach that's worth experimenting with would be to have multiple materials but only one mesh - you'd still get (somewhat) progressive loading. BUT
2. Are you sure you'd be better off with "chunks" loading sequentially rather than one big texture taking a huge amount of time? Sure, it'll improve a bit in terms of timeouts and caching, but the tradeoff is having big chunks of your mesh be textureless, which is noticeable and unasthetic.
3. There are a few approaches that would mitigate your problem. First, it's important to understand that texture loading optimization techniques - while common in game engines - aren't really part of threejs or what it's built for. You'll never get the near-seamless LODs or GPU optimization techniques that you'll get with UE4 or Unity. Furthermore webGL - while having made many strides over the past decade - is not ideal for handling vast texture sizes, not at the GPU level (since it's based on OpenGL ES, suited primarily for mobile devices) and certainly not at the caching level - we're still dealing with broswers here. You won't find a lot of webGL work done with vast textures of the dimensions you refer to.

Having said that,

A. A [loader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/Loader) will let you do other things while your textures are loading so your user isn't staring at an 'unfinished mesh'. It lets you be pretty clever with dynamic loading times and UX design. Additionally, take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/knee-cola/37875bc4359609b96c9f329cd2a68fa1) to give you an idea for what a progressive texture loader could look like. A much more involved technique, that's JPEG specific, can be found [here](https://github.com/bompo/streamingtextures) but I wouldn't approach it unless you're comfortable with low-level graphics programming.

B. Threejs [*does*](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lod.html) have a basic implementation of LOD although I haven't tinkered with it myself and am not sure it's useful for textures; that said, the basic premise to inquire into is whether you can load progressively higher-resolution files on a per-need basis, just like Google Earth does it for example.

C. This is out of the scope of your question - but I'd look into what happens under the hood in Unity's webgl export (which is based on threejs), and what kind of clever tricks are being employed there for similar purposes.

Finally, does your project *have* to be in webgl? For something ambitious and demanding, sometimes "proper" openGL / DX makes much more sense.

Comment: `Finally, does your project have to be in webgl? For something ambitious and demanding, sometimes "proper" openGL / DX makes much more sense.` Errrm, openGL / DX do not run in the browser, served through http.

Comment: that's right - I was questioning the need to run this through the browser in the first place. OP's use case didn't strike me as necessarily involving webgl and I wanted to share other options of tackling the problem; I think that hardly warrants a downvote.

Comment: I think it's more valid to question the OP's use case than his stack. I think that a few assumptions can safely be made. 1. someone who asks a question about Javascript may not know C++ or some other such language that is needed to work with OpenGL / DX. 2. someone who asks a question about javascript most likely wants to run that code in a browser (because of the visual component, you don't expect node.js to be the target.

Comment: The same applies for `WebGL`, someone asking a question specifically for WebGL either: 1. does not know how to work in OpenGL / DX. 2. does know how to work in OpenGL / DX. In the latter case, i would also assume that one would know the shortcomings of the WebGL api, and the features of another. In both cases, the answer does not make sense. [Please look at this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357466/the-three-js-tag-has-really-bad-questions), and try to help improve [tag:three.js]

Comment: This question is horrible and needs to be edited or closed.

Comment: But your answer i think would be on the wrong path too. 1. does not sound like advice for a programming forum, even if you did it in 3ds max, you would still program it with `maxscript` rather than do all this manually. Regardless there is no reason why this mesh generation along with uvs could not be generated on the fly in JS with three.js. (user may not know how to use either Blender or 3dsMax).

Comment: 2. is completely missing the issue, he's hitting the MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE limit (it's very confusing, and poorly formatted but `(But it's look very good when it is working)` indicates that the texture of this size does not even work on different devices. It's not about timeouts and caching here, he can load one huge chunk and extract the segments he needs. It's how this data is formatted for the gpu that fails.

Comment: 3. is actually a good answer but without mentioning all the engines. These are all graphics algorithms that you are referring to, but it's not obvious, and the reader may not know anything about these engines. It would be better to just describe techniques, for example `what does LOD mean`.

Comment: 1. It’s quite common, in SO like all places, to offer a better tool for a job when the OP isn’t necessarily considering the best option. I am not the first nor the last to mention that a lot of what’s perceived as programmatic 3D work can (And is) actually be done much more efficiently with a 3D program and I’m surprised you’re laboring under the impression that just because this is a programming forum we must avoid mention of other tools, which strikes me as a pretty pedantic approach.

Comment: With regards to the rest of your comments - I think this exchange is fruitless and misses the mark, which is helping OP (whose question you seem to resent to begin with). I’m not sure what you’re hoping to accomplish by this wall of text (criticizing and passing judgement on my understanding of the question and attempt to help OP out? What’s the end game here and are you sure it’s worth your effort?) - in either case, have a good evening.

Comment: I am hoping to improve the tag: [tag:three.js]

Comment: `Thanks, But I don't have a problem with loading time... ` is how your wall of text for an answer was received. At least I elaborated on what is wrong with it (number 2 in your answer). By wall of text I only mean good things, it's the effort you took and your precious time. I don't like that a bad question has been posted, and that this much effort went into answering it. And then im especially ticked by the OP's comment which seems unappreciative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156233/discussion-between-pailhead-and-aquavitae).

Comment: Fair enough - I guess I was already frustrated by OP's lackluster response and mistook your tone. My apologies. (For the record, I agree this is a bad question and am following the debate on GitHub...)